# How to calculate vectors?

Tags: vector

Given

```
vector a=(m, 3), vector b=(1, m+1),
```

if vector a is perpendicular to vector b, calculate the value of m？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> f vector a is perpendicular to vector b, calculate the value of m

```
v1 = {m, 3}
v2 = {1, m + 1}
Solve[Dot[v1, v2] == 0, m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]